# Is a symmetric matrix a subspace of nxn matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $M$ be a vector space for all 2x2 matrices.

Show that the set of all the symmetric matrices $M2$={$B ∈ M2 : B=B^t$} is a subspace of M.

---

My solution:

1. The null matrix is symmetric

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

---

2. Let $B$, $C$ $∈$ $M2$, where $B = B^t$, $C=C^t$. Then, $B+C=B^t + C^t$.

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}a&c\\c&b\end{pmatrix}$$
$$C = \begin{pmatrix}d&f\\f&e\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B+C = \begin{pmatrix}a+d&c+f\\c+f&b+e\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B^t = \begin{pmatrix}a&c\\c&b\end{pmatrix}$$
$$C^t = \begin{pmatrix}d&f\\f&e\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B^t+C^t = \begin{pmatrix}a+d&c+f\\c+f&b+e\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, $B + C ∈ M2$.

---

3. Let $B ∈ M2$, $θ ∈ R$. Then, $θB = θB^t$

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}a&c\\c&b\end{pmatrix}$$ $$θB = \begin{pmatrix}θa&θc\\θc&θb\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B^t = \begin{pmatrix}a&c\\c&b\end{pmatrix}$$ $$θB^t = \begin{pmatrix}θa&θc\\θc&θb\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, $θB ∈ M2$.

---

### So, $M2$ is, indeed, a subspace of $M$.

I am just learning linear algebra, so I apologize if I've made any mistakes.

Also, I just got into this community, so I am still learning the formatting, so I apologize for any mistakes as well.

Appreciate all the answers.

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: Your solution is correct. Just keep in mind that the three properties you checked implies $M2$ is a subspace indirectly, so it would be more rigorous to mention this fact by adding something like "... and we know that these three conditions are sufficient for a subset of a vector space to be vector space itself."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is fine.

Or you could have noticed that there is a basis for your space:

$$m_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, m_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},
m_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Show a $2\times 2$ matrix is symmetric if and only if it can be written as $$am_1+bm_2+cm_3$$
for some real $a,b,c.$

But this answer requires knowledge of bases. Your answer is more direct.

But the general rule makes it unnecessary to prove many individual case:

> If $V$ is a real vector space, and $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\in V$ then:
> $$W=\{v\in V\mid \exists a_1,\dots,a_k\in \mathbb R(v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_kv_k\}$$

Comment: So if I show that there is a basis for a certain space, that means it is a subspace? And the dimension of that space would be 3 in this case, correct?

Comment: Yes, you have to find a basis, and show that a vector is in your set if and only if the vector is a linear combination of the basis. Technically, you don’t need it to be a basis. The $v_i$ can be linearly dependent, it’s just not very useful. In any event, you don’t have to prove they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to prove this is to note that if $A,B$ are symmetric matrices then since $(\lambda A)^T = \lambda A^T = \lambda A$ and $(A+B)^T = A^T+B^T = A +B$, so are $\lambda A$ and $A+B$.